# KnockoutJS - firing a subscription only after initialization

Tags: knockout.js

I have a situation where I want to do tasks when an observable changes, so I set up a subscription - however I do not want this to fire right when the item is created.

http://jsfiddle.net/ciel/EeZjH/

Basically, "Binding" is already set for each item when it comes in from the controller - so I don't want to publish the changes yet. only if they change from what the initialized value is. Is this plausible?

```
function Item(data) {
  this.Binding = ko.observable(data);

  this.Binding.subscribe(function (newValue) {
    console.log("The Binding is Now " + newValue);
  });
}

var viewModel = {
  Options: ko.observableArray([{
    "Value": "1",
      "Name": "One"
  }, {
    "Value": "2",
      "Name": "Two"
  }, {
    "Value": "3",
      "Name": "Three"
  }]),
  Items: ko.observableArray([])
};

viewModel.Items.push(new Item("1"));
viewModel.Items.push(new Item("2"));
viewModel.Items.push(new Item("3"));

viewModel.output = ko.computed(function () {
  return JSON.stringify(
  viewModel.Items().map(

  function (i) {
    return i.Binding();
  }));
});

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Comment: If I understand correctly you are trying to avoid triggering the function bound to `Binding` when the object is created? I just ran your fiddle and that callback is actually NOT being called. Could you further explain the problem?

Comment: Your assumption is correct. The fiddle seems to be broken from yesterday, no idea why. I think jsFiddle is upgrading or something and it is interfering.

Comment: If you examine the console on the fiddle, it is throwing all kinds of random errors that I think have nothing to do with my code. These errors are happening in every fiddle I run no matter what the framework is, so I am fairly certain it has nothing to do with my code.

Comment: Ok, I downloaded the code and tested it locally, the callback is still not being called (i.e. there's no "The Binding is Now ..." in the js console of the browser) What version of KO are you using?

Comment: The newest, to my knowledge.

Comment: Version 2.2.0 is the one I am testing with.

Comment: Did you tested it again? I'm not seeing the problem you mention.

Comment: What you've described is how subscribe works. It already does what you want.

Answer (score 1):

```
ko.observable.fn.beforeAndAfterSubscribe = function (callback, target) {
 var _oldValue;
 this.subscribe(function (oldValue) {
     _oldValue = oldValue;
 }, null, 'beforeChange');
   this.subscribe(function (newValue) {
     callback.call(target, _oldValue, newValue);
 });
};
```

- See more at: http://ideone.com/NPpNcB#sthash.xU5GK0Kc.dpuf